# Как вывести дату

Tags: php

Я из базы данных получаю дату публикации поста `2019-12-18 12:11:57` в таком виде. Я бы хотел выводить на сайте дату таким образом: `18 декабря, 2019`. Я понимаю как вывести название месяца, имея число месяца, но я не понимаю как мне вытаскивать год, месяц и число через дефис, которые разделяет эти цифры.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$time = strtotime("2019-12-18 12:11:57");
$date = date('d M Y', $time);
var_dump($date);
```

Результат

```
18 Dec 2019
```

Форматы доступные вот тут можно поглядеть https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php

Учтите, что для отображения месяца на русском языке, в системе должна быть русская локаль.

Comment: по поводу локали почти соседний вопрос - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1062527/223826

Comment: @teran Я делал на js, думаю такое же сделаю на php, я создавал массив с названиями месяцов, получал нужную мне цифру месяца и выводил месяц [по числу] из массива