# Как перевести на укр, или рус месяц из функции date ()?

Tags: php

Как перевести на укр, или рус месяц из функции `date()`?

```
date(" j F Y \р\о\к\у");
```

Выводит: `24 December 2019 року`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

никак, и это [документировано](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php)

> Для форматирования дат на других языках используйте вместо `date()` функции `setlocale()` и `strftime()`.

в целом вы можете сделать нечто подобное:

```
$months = [ 1=> "января", "февраля", .... ];
$m = $months[date("n")];
echo date("j $m Y года");
```

зы: не надо экранировать символы в строке

либо используйте смену локали и вышеупомянутые функции. правда, вероятно. вы получите названия месяцев в именительном падеже, что тоже не совсем вас устроит (если это применимо к украинскому, конечно).